# Using isight/facetime builtin camera

Tags: osx

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I am trying to get the builtin camera of my MacBook Pro to work with the libuvc driver:

rosrun libuvc_camera camera_node vendor:=0x106B

[ INFO] [1404251751.441933000]: Opening camera with vendor=0x0, product=0x0, serial="", index=0
uvc_find_device: No such device (-4)

What am I doing wrong?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/181939/using-isight/facetime-builtin-camera/) by [J.M.T.](https://answers.ros.org/users/3816/j.m.t./) on ROS Answers with karma: 266 on 2014-07-01

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Turned out the new facetime cameras are [pci devices](http://mactaris.blogspot.com/2013/07/webcam-settings-20-will-support.html) so there is no libuvc support

---

Originally posted by [J.M.T.](https://answers.ros.org/users/3816/j.m.t./) with karma: 266 on 2014-07-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gunshi](https://answers.ros.org/users/26575/gunshi/) on 2016-04-27**:
Hi, do you know by any chance from  which macbook model onwards this happened?
I have a late 2011 macbook pro, on OS X 10.11.12, and i was wondering if it supports uvc.

**Comment by [Yue](https://answers.ros.org/users/27915/yue/) on 2016-10-16**:
I'm also interested. Any update?
Thanks